# I cant get this message off my dashboard

Tags: ford, fiesta

I cannot get this message of my dashboard. I have tried every button in the car but there doesn't seem to be any corresponding button. Any help would be great thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome, please post a photo, and state the make and model/year of the vehicle.

Comment: What is the message? And do you mean how to you get the message off?

Comment: Have you read the manual? Bluetooth connectivity functions are always detailed in the manual

Comment: What about the button 'Debond' just below the message?

Answer (score 2):

Try the large knob in the middle, between the CD and TA buttons. Try left.

EDIT: [2012 Ford Fiesta Owner's Manual](https://www.fordservicecontent.com/Ford_Content/catalog/owner_guides/12fstog3e.pdf)